# getting a script to run for multiple datatables

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, pug

I have a couple tables that I've created using Jade in addition with bootstrap and jQuery DataTables. I've included some code to make individual column filtering possible; however, it only fully works on the first table even though they are both identified by the same ID that the function is being applied to. The code is as follows:

```
script.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.datatable tfoot th').each( function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' +title+'" />');
            });

            var table = $('.datatable').DataTable();

            table.columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;

                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        } );
```

as per the example that can be found in the DataTables API: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

my tables are both identified with the ID .datatable, and they have according headers & footers that work with the code. Both tables show textboxes as a result of the function, but only the first one actually performs the filtering. Any advice on how I could use this function successfully for multiple tables would be appreciated, thanks!

my full code is as follows:

```
extends layout

block content
head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    link(href='css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js')
    title Bootstrap Example
body
    script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js')
    script(src='js/bootstrap.min.js')
    .container
        .jumbotron
            .mark
                h2 Bootstrap/Datatables Test Page
        .megasearch
            h3 Search All Tables
            input#Search_All
        br
        br



        // TABLE ONE 
        table.datatable.table.table-hover.table-striped.table-bordered
            thead
                tr
                    th #
                    th Name
                    th Type
                    th Battery
            tfoot
                tr
                    th #
                    th Name
                    th Spice
                    th Approval 
            tbody
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 1
                    td BOSS RC-1
                    td Loop
                    td Yes
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 2
                    td Line 6 DL4
                    td Delay
                    td Yes
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 3
                    td Polara
                    td Reverb
                    td Yes
        br
        br              
        // TABLE TWO 
        table.datatable.table.table-hover.table-striped.table-bordered
            thead
                tr
                    th #
                    th Name
                    th Spice
                    th Approval
            tfoot
                tr
                    th #
                    th Name
                    th Spice
                    th Approval                     
            tbody
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 1
                    td Pickle
                    td No
                    td Yes
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 2
                    td Jalapeno
                    td Yes
                    td Yes
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 3
                    td Pickled Onions
                    td No
                    td Yes
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 3
                    td Pickled Onions
                    td No
                    td Yes                              
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 3
                    td Pickled Onions
                    td No
                    td Yes  
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 3
                    td Pickled Onions
                    td No
                    td Yes  
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 3
                    td Pickled Onions
                    td No
                    td Yes  
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 3
                    td Pickled Onions
                    td No
                    td Yes  
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 3
                    td Pickled Onions
                    td No
                    td Yes  
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 3
                    td Pickled Onions
                    td No
                    td Yes  
                tr
                    th(scope='row') 3
                    td Pickled Onions
                    td No
                    td Yes                                                                                                  

    // SCRIPTS REQUIRED FOR DATATABLES AND FUNCTION FOR SEARCH_ALL      
    script(src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')
    script(src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')
    script(src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js')
    script.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.datatable').DataTable({
                "pagingType": "full_numbers"
            });


            // THIS IS THE GLOBAL SEARCH CODE
            $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnFilterAll=function(oSettings,sInput,iColumn,bRegex,bSmart){
                var settings = $.fn.dataTableSettings;
                for (var i = 0; i < settings.length; i++) {
                    settings[i].oInstance.fnFilter(sInput, iColumn, bRegex, bSmart);
                }
            };

            var table = $(".datatable").dataTable();


            $("#Search_All").keyup(function () {
                // Filter on the column (the index) of this element
                table.fnFilterAll(this.value);
            });
        });

    script.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.datatable tfoot th').each( function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' +title+'" />');
            });

            var table = $('.datatable').DataTable();

            table.columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;

                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        } );
```

Comment: 1) `.datatable` is not an ID; it's a class. 2) If you're using DataTables' class name to make the selections, the correct class to use would be `.dataTable` (with a capital `T`). Without being able to see your table structure, it's difficult to tell what the problem might be.

Comment: I just added my full code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You just added the class to the Datatable. Use an unique id-attribute for both instead. like datatable1, datatable2.

Then wrap your code in a function with the id as a parameter:

```
function initMyDataTable(id){
        $('#'+id+' tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' +title+'" />');
        });

        var table = $('#'+id).DataTable();

        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
}
```

Now you can call this function with the ID of the desired table:

```
initMyDataTable('datatable1');
initMyDataTable('datatable2');
```